# RanorexSpy XPath not indexing elements in the right DOM structure order

Tags: xpath, ranorex

When searching for elements with the same class, RanorexSpy finds all the elements, but fails to index them in the order of the dom structure. Is there any function or another way to search for the elements or is this a bug?

I have setup a simple website for an example.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="class_sample">1</div>
    <div class="class_sample">2</div>
    <div class="class_sample">3</div>
    <div class="class_sample">4</div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="class_sample">5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="class_sample">6</div>
    <div class="class_sample">7</div>
    <div class="class_sample">8</div>
    <div class="class_sample">9</div>
    <div class="class_sample">10</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I have 10 divs with the same class name and the 5th element is nested inside 2 divs.

When searching for the element in xpath: `/dom[@caption='Document']/body//div[@class='class_sample']`, I get all the divs with the class, but Ranorex failes to index them in order of the dom structure.

The first 4 divs are indexed in order, but as soon as I try to find the element with the index of '5' (which is nested). It skips to the 6th div. The 5th element has the index of 10.

Here are the links to pictures.

Wrong indexing:

[image: Wrong indexing]

[image: Wrong indexing]

Answer (score 0):

Try `/dom[@caption='Document']/body/descendant::div[@class='class_sample'][5]` or `/dom[@caption='Document']/body/descendant::div[@class='class_sample'][10]`.

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4P6yh has an example for `descendant::div[@class='class_sample'][5]` selecting `<div class="class_sample">5</div>`, https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4P6yh/1 has an example for `descendant::div[@class='class_sample'][10]` selecting `<div class="class_sample">10</div>`.

`(//div[@class='class_sample'])[5]` selects `<div class="class_sample">5</div>` at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4P6yh/2 and `(//div[@class='class_sample'])[10]` selects `<div class="class_sample">10</div>` at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4P6yh/3.

On the other hand, `//div[@class='class_sample'][5]` right selects `<div class="class_sample">6</div>` at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4P6yh/4 as `//div` is short for `/desendant-or-self::node()/div` so `//div[@class='class_sample'][5]` is `/desendant-or-self::node()/div[@class='class_sample'][5]`.

Comment: The first xpath returns the 6th element, the second returns the 5th, but I need the index to be in order [5] must point to the 5th element and not to the 6th.

Comment: Well, XPath not necessarily defines an order but `descendant::div[@class='class_sample'][5]` should select the fifth descendant `div` element with the `class` attribute being `class_sample`. Anyway, what you could also try it to wrap your whole path into parenthesis e.g. `(/dom[@caption='Document']/body//div[@class='class_sample'])` and apply the positional predicate on that expression `(/dom[@caption='Document']/body//div[@class='class_sample'])[5]` or `(/dom[@caption='Document']/body//div[@class='class_sample'])]10]`. But I don't know your engine, this is just a suggestion based on XPath.

Comment: Nothing seems to work.. The descendant tag returns the 6th element, but thanks for the suggestion.